# GSVM-RU Implementation

Tags: svm

Are there any implementations (free or otherwise) of GSVM-RU (granular support vector machines - repetitive under-sampling) as described by [SVMs Modeling for Highly Imbalanced Classification](http://www.mcafee.com/au/resources/white-papers/wp-svm-modeling-for-highly-imbalanced-classification.pdf) ?

Comment: I think you should spell these out. People from many countries read these and acronyms can be hard to read in translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across this, but can't vouch for it's accuracy: https://code.google.com/p/ml-ml-tb/source/browse/trunk/util/svm-util/gsvmru.m